# How do i call the randInt() function inside the MathUtils object in the following code?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to call the randInt() function situated inside the MathUtils object in the following javascript file. I want to pass the arguments to randInt() from another javascript file and get the returned result. I'm not getting the output by the normal function calling method. Please suggest something.

```
(function (global, factory) {
typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? factory(exports) :
typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['exports'], factory) :
(factory((global.THREE = global.THREE || {})));
}(this, (function (exports) { 'use strict';

 exports.Math=MathUtils;

var MathUtils = {

    DEG2RAD: Math.PI / 180,
    RAD2DEG: 180 / Math.PI,

    // Random integer from <low, high> interval

    randInt: function ( low, high ) {

        return low + Math.floor( Math.random() * ( high - low + 1 ) );

    },

    // Random float from <low, high> interval

    randFloat: function ( low, high ) {

        return low + Math.random() * ( high - low );

    }
}
})));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `MathUtils` was never exported inside the JS file, and even when you do export it the object lives inside the `THREE` namespace.

```js
(function(global, factory) {
  typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? factory(exports) :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['exports'], factory) :
    (factory((global.THREE = global.THREE || {})));
}(this, (function(exports) {
  'use strict';

  var MathUtils = {

    DEG2RAD: Math.PI / 180,
    RAD2DEG: 180 / Math.PI,

    // Random integer from <low, high> interval

    randInt: function(low, high) {

      return low + Math.floor(Math.random() * (high - low + 1));

    },

    // Random float from <low, high> interval

    randFloat: function(low, high) {

      return low + Math.random() * (high - low);

    }

  }

  // NOTE THIS LINE
  exports.MathUtils = MathUtils

})));

// IN ANOTHER JS FILE:

console.log(THREE.MathUtils.randInt(1, 10))
```

Comment: I edited the file and used exports.Math = MathUtils; to get the javascript "Math" features. Is that okay?

Comment: You still won't be overriding the JS global `Math` object. The new method will be accessed as `THREE.Math.randInt` rather than `Math.randInt`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used THREE.Math.randInt after exports.Math = MathUtils; and it worked.